# Enable WPF DataGrid Panning?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that I allow to expand vertically as far as needed, and so there is no need to scroll or pan the content within the DataGrid itself. However, it's inside of a Window that has a ScrollViewer.

When I run it, the DataGrid grows vertically to allow all rows as expected, and the ScrollBar along the edge of the Window appears as expected. But I can only touch/pan up and down if I do it on the areas of the Window that lie outside of the DataGrid itself. The DataGrid accepts and effectively blocks the input (which is not unexpected.)

So how can I make the DataGrid "pass" this touch/pan input upward to it's container, i.e. the Window, so that the Window will know it needs to scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but I thought the visual tree in WPF bubbles upwards. This would mean that your DataGrid, as I am interpreting it right now, would capture the event and handle it correctly as you mentioned.

But once that's done, it bubbles up to its parent (the window) thus not passing the event to your scrollviewer. It does this because the datagrid in scrollviewer are probably siblings instead of having a parent/child relationship.

One option would be to setup a command to handle this behaviour.
Or you could use the dispatcher:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke( () => 
           control.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewerChannelBtns.VerticalOffset + 50);
```

Comment: The ScrollViewer is a child of the Window.

I know the event bubbles upwards. But I believe the default behavior for controls handling this type of event is for them to consume it and not forward to their parents.

Same is true with other controls. And normally it isn't a prob, but the DataGrid is so big that I need to scroll the Window when I touch and drag on it.

I suppose I need to hook into the correct Preview___ event (which will come down from the top) that gets fired when panning on the DataGrid...but I don't even know what event(s) are used by panning, and I can't find any docs for it

Answer (score 0):

In xaml

```
ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both"
```